# How to show and hide div based on php condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

My php code

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    echo "logged in";
?>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("loggedin").style.display = 'none';
    </script>
<?php
}
else {
    echo "not logged in";

?>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("public").style.display = 'none';
    </script>
<?php
}    
?>
```

and html is

```
<li>
        <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="public">
             <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">   Login   </a>
                     </div>
                     <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="loggedin">
                  <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">   Loggedin   </a>
                         </div>
                </li>
```

I just wanna show one div at a time. How to fix this?? However php echo funtion is working based on condition.

Comment: you could put your div in the PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the JavaScript code inside your PHP, just put the divs in there.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<li>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
?>

    <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="loggedin">
        <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">   Loggedin   </a>
    </div>

<?php
} else {
?>

    <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="public">
        <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">   Login   </a>
    </div>

<?php
}    
?>

</li>
```

Comment: fyi, there is a handy language construct called empty()

Answer (score 1):

Let PHP handle the work and don't involve JavaScript at all.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){

    echo '<div style="float:right; display:block;">
             <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">Login</a>
          </div>';

    } else {

    echo '<div style="float:right; display:block;">
             <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton">Loggedin</a>
          </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some logic:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
    $logged = true;
} else {
    $logged = false;
}

?>
```

Your page content:

```
<?php if ($logged): ?>
    <div>I am displayed!</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>I am displayed instead!</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple php:

```
<?php
if($id > 0){
    echo '<div class="">'.$id.'</div>';        
}
?>
```

Or add hide class to div in php:

```
<div class="oneClassName <?php if($id > 0){ echo 'hide'; } ?>">.....</div>
```

And css:

```
.hide{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your divs with php

```
<li>
    <?if(($_SESSION["loggedin"]??false) === true):?>
        <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="loggedin">
            <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton"> Loggedin </a>
        </div>
    <?else:?>
        <div style="float:right;display:block;" id="public">
            <a href="login_signup/login.php" class="myButton"> Login </a>
        </div>
    <?endif;?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
    <input type="hidden" id="status" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedin']; ?>">
    <script>
    var status = document.getElementById("hidden").value;
    if(status){
     // show 
    }else{
     // hide
    }
   </script>
```